# Apache POI XWPF Paragraph on Same Page

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I have a paragraph which contains some text , image and and some text . All these 3 sections are present on a new line .How do i ensure that the paragraph should be rendered on the same page only when  there is not enough space on the current page .If the space is there on the current page then it should get rendered on the same page. I have used :

```
    XWPFParagraph p11 = doc.createParagraph();
    p11.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    XWPFRun r11 = p11.createRun();
    p11.setPageBreak(true);
```

But this does not help as p11 paragraph is rendered on  new page every time even if there is space on the existing page .

Answer (score 0):

```
XWPFParagraph p11 = doc.createParagraph();
p11.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
XWPFRun r11 = p11.createRun();
p11.setPageBreak(true);
XWPFParagraph p12 = doc.addParagraph();
XWPFParagraph p13 = doc.addParagraph();
XWPFParagraph p14 = doc.addParagraph();
```

Comment: welcome to SO, you 'd rather explain why your code will solve his problem.